# including CSS file in AdminLTE template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dashboard

I want to use this Template called 'AdminLTE' [ https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE] .
and when I save the ont-awesome.min.css from the link on my pc, and include it in my code, it just doesn't work.

any Idea guys? is it the same for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply
You need to download font files also
For that check that css you downloaded and search for url
you will get fonts required.
Download it to pc and link it in that css and you are ready to go

Comment: Thank you, that was the case, I've downloaded all the files and it worked perfectly.